# Creating a method which contains a switch statement based on one of the parameters passed into the method

Tags: java, string, switch-statement

I am writing a method, `createMessage()` which will take two parameters - the type of message and the message itself.

So far I have achieved this by having both parameters of type `String`. The type of message will be one of three; instruction, error or success. The method contains a switch statement that will edit the message in a certain way based on its type.

The method will look something like this:

```
public void createMessage(String messageType, String message) {
    String output = "";
    switch(messageType) {
    case "instruction":
        output = "INSTRUCTION: " + message + "\n";
        //edits required for an instruction
        break;  
    case "error":
        output = "ERROR: " + message + "\n";
        //edits required for an error
        break;    
    case "success":
        output = "SUCCESS: " + message + "\n";
        //edits required for a success
        break;    
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid message type: " + messageType);
}
```

This method would be called as `createMessage("instruction", "Enter your name:");`, whereas I would prefer to not have to use quotation marks for giving the message type - `createMessage(instruction, "Enter your name:");`.

**Question**: What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Consider creating an enum?

Comment: Enum is the best option for this answer. Look at @youssef Lahoud answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per comment you could use an enum as following:

```
public enum MessageType {
    INSTRUCTION, ERROR, SUCCESS;    
}
```

And your method be refactored as following:

```
public void createMessage(MessageType messageType, String message) {
    String output = "";
    switch(messageType) {
    case INSTRUCTION:
        output = "INSTRUCTION: " + message + "\n";
        //edits required for an instruction
        break;  
    case ERROR:
        output = "ERROR: " + message + "\n";
        //edits required for an error
        break;    
    case SUCCESS:
        output = "SUCCESS: " + message + "\n";
        //edits required for a success
        break;    
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid message type: " + messageType);
    }
}
```

But if you really need to have behaviors on your message entity, don't delegate it to an external method, rather create a Message class:

```
public class Message {
    private MessageType type;
    private String text;

    public Message(MessageType type, String text) {
        this.type = type;
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String buildOutput() {
        return type + text;
    }

    // other behaviors here
}
```

And enforce its responsibility within your application to handle based on types and texts the required behaviors.

That would enforce the Single Responsibility Principle (SRP) and you would have a better (and easier) testability.

Answer (score 2):

You can use enumeration. Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) tutorial if you don't know how to use them.

```
public enum MessageType{
    INSTRUCTION, ERROR, SUCCESS
}
```

Plus you can switch on enums in clean way:

```
public void createMessage(MessageType messageType, String message) {
    String output = "";
    switch(messageType) {
    case INSTRUCTION://code break;
    case ERROR://code break;
    case SUCCESS://code break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using an enum, as you can then ensure that all message types passed to the method are valid.

```
public enum MessageType {
   ERROR, INSTRUCTION, SUCCESS;    
}
```

You can then use the `name()` method on the message type to get the name of the enum member, and then covert it to uppercase. It would probably be better practice to implement this in the MessageType enum, but to fit your design I made it separate.

```
public String createMessage(MessageType type, String message) {
   return String.format("%s: %s%n", type.name().toUpperCase(), message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An enumeration would be a huge improvement because you explicitly define the cases to be handled. But it will not help you to get rid of the switch satement which is sometimes considered a code smell.

Therefore you should also consider using three separate functions.

Another option would be to use `Message` as a base class ande derive `ErrorMessage` etc. from it. Each subclass will know how to handle the output.